# Searching in an set of pointers, using a custom Compare functor

Tags: c++, stl, find, set

I was just wondering if the solution I just figured out works fine in all cases.

I have an Server class, handling user visits between pages, which are stored as a Page class, with a single attribute being the relative URL of the Page. I also store requests from Page to Page, also stored as a Request class, having references to both the referrer and target Pages.

The difficulty lies in that Page objects store two set of pointers to Request objects: one for targets (outgoing requests) and one for referrers (incoming requests); searching in this set should be done using a given URL, in order to get the Request associated to two Pages.

The call would look like this: `Request * referrer = page.Referrer("/page2.html");`

Now for my current code:

```cpp
// page.h

#include <set> 
#include <string> 
#include "request.h"

class Page
{
    struct compReferrers
    {
        bool operator()(Request * const &, Request * const &) const;
    }; // struct compReferrers

    struct compTargets
    {
        bool operator()(Request * const &, Request * const &) const;
    }; // struct compReferrers

    std::string url_;
    std::set<Request *, compReferrers> referrers_;
    std::set<Request *, compTargets> targets_;

    public:
        Page(const std::string & url): url_(url) {}

        // Problematic methods
        Request * Referrer(const std::string & url) const;
        Request * Target(const std::string & url) const;

        // Getter
        inline std::string Url() const { return url_; }
}; // class Page

// page.cpp

#include "page.h"

Request * Page::Referrer(const std::string & url) const
{
    Page referrer(url), target("dummy");
    Request req(referrer, target);
    std::set<Request *, compRefferers>::const_iterator it;
    it = referrers_.find(&req);
    if (it != referrers_.end())
    {
        return *it;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

bool Page::compReferrers::operator()(Request * const & left,
        Request * const & right) const
{
    if (left == 0) return true;
    else if (right == 0) return false;
    else return left->Referrer().Url() < right->Referrer().Url();
}

bool Page::compTargets::operator()(Request * const & left, 
        Request * const & right) const
{
    if (left == 0) return true;
    else if (right == 0) return false;
    else return left->Target().Url() < right->Target().Url();
}

// request.h

class Page;

class Request
{
    public:
        Request(Page & referrer, Page & target):
            referrer_(referrer), target_(target), visits_(0) {}

        // Useful code
        inline void Visit() { ++visits_; }
        inline Page & Referrer() const { return referrer_; }
        inline Page & Target() const { return target_; }

    private:
        Page & referrer_;
        Page & target_;
        std::size_t visits_;
}; // class Request
```

Is there a correct / better way of doing this ?

Comment: I think your only other option is to use std::find_if, and that would have worse performance than set::find().

Comment: Why don't you store the requests in `std::map<Url, Request*>`? Or, better, in `boost::multi_index` see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582310/avoiding-copies-when-using-structs-in-stl-sets-and-custom-comparison-function

Comment: I can't use boost (this is homework destined to teach us how to use the STL), and I don't see how I could work out an N-M relationship with a `std::map<Url, Request *>` (N referrers, M targets)